# Defining Map of Tasks using User ID as Key

Tags: apex, query, class, map

My goal is to send an email to users with their respective open tasks. I tried: UserInfo.getUserId () but I realized that it only works for the current user. Therefore, I'm trying to create a Map with the User Id as the Key and its respective tasks.
What I have so far:

```
    public EmailTasksWeekly() {
       User[] uList = [Select ID FROM User];
       Set<String> exstIds = new Set<String>();
       tk = [Select ID, OwnerId, Status, Subject, What.Name, ActivityDate FROM Task WHERE Status = 'Open'];
    
       for(User u : uList) {
        for(Task t : tk) {
            if(u.Id == t.OwnerId) {
        exstIds.add(u.Id);
            }
        }
       }
    
    Map<Id,List<Task>> mapTasks = new Map<Id,List<Task>>();
    for(Task k : tk) {
        List<Task> TasksForKey = mapTasks.get(k.OwnerId);
        if (TasksForKey == null) {
            TasksForKey = new List<Task>();
            mapTasks.put(k.OwnerId, TasksForKey);
        }
        TasksForKey.add(k);
    }
    
    tasks = [Select ID, OwnerId, Status, Subject, What.Name, ActivityDate FROM Task WHERE Status = 'Open' AND OwnerId = :mapTasks]; //It's the query I need to send correct tasks to correct users
    
    }
```

Comment: Are you having some problem with your current code?

Comment: Yes, I can't use the map in the query defined in "tasks" at the end of the code. This part is crucial, because from this query I will send the right tasks to the right users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of querying all users, we can just build the list from only open tasks, and only active users. Here's code to get you started:

```
public void EmailTasksWeekly() {
    Map<Id, List<Task>> tasksByUser = new Map<Id, List<Task>>();
    for(Task taskRecord: [SELECT OwnerId, Status, Subject, What.Name, ActivityDate FROM Task WHERE IsClosed = FALSE AND Owner.IsActive = TRUE]) {
        List<Task> userTasks = tasksByUser.get(taskRecord.OwnerId);
        if(userTasks == null) {
            tasksByUser.put(taskRecord.OwnerId, userTasks = new List<Task>());
        }
        userTasks.add(taskRecord);
    }
    // We now have all active users with one or more tasks
}
```

There's other ways to write this as well, but this is probably one of the most efficient versions of this kind of algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much, sfdcfox. I'm not very used to using Maps, do you know if I can call it in a query, as I'm trying to do at the end of my code?

Comment: @SabrinaT. We've already queried all the tasks, you don't need to query them again.